# How to set values of class attributes through a list

Tags: python

I have a class with many attributes of type *double*.
The goal is to define a subset of these attributes in a list that will be iterated over and the corresponding values should be changed.

I would like to avoid referencing to the attributes of the class by their name, since I don't want to use any typed in str in the code.

```py
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0.0
        self.b = 0.0
        self.c = 0.0

foo = Foo()

variables = [foo.a, foo.b]

for i in range(len(variables)):
    variables[i] = 1.0

print(foo.a)
```

This code returns 0.0 which is correct for the code above. The question is, how to write the code, so that the result would be the updated value of 1.0?

Comment: That's not possible. A float is immutable, so passing just that value around doesn't allow you to modify it. You can only assign a new value to the attribute of your class, which requires that you at least pass your class around.

Comment: `variables` is not a list of references to your instance attributes; it's a list of references to the *values* of the instance attribute.

Comment: I would recommend to rethink your data structure and combine the numeric attributes in one or a few attributes as arrays. A rule of thumb is that an object should not have much more than ten attributes just to keep a good overview.

Answer (score 1):

`variables` should be a list of attribute names, not the values of those attributes.

```
variables = ['a', 'b']
for v in variables:
    setattr(foo, v, 1.0)
```

Python doesn't have a notion of "bound attributes" which would let you store a reference to `foo.a` directly in the list, though you could store object/name pairs in the list.

```
variables = [(foo, 'a'), (foo, 'b')]
for obj, attr in variables:
    setattr(obj, attr, 1.0)
```

---

You could make the attributes properties instead, which would allow you, given

```
from functool import partial


class Foo(object):
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter(self, v):
    def a(self):
        self._a = v

    # Likewise for b and c
    # I leave it as an exercise to define a custom
    # descriptor that would let you write
    # a = my_property(0.0)
    # b = my_property(0.0)
    # c = my_property(0.0)

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0.0
        self.b = 0.0
        self.c = 0.0

foo = Foo()
```

to write

```
foo = Foo()

variables = [partial(x.fset, foo) for x in [Foo.a, Foo.b]]

for v in variables:
    v(1.0)
```

It's similar to the tuple solution above, but shifts the boilerplate into the definition of `variables` rather than the loop that sets the values.

Comment: *"I would like to avoid referencing to the attributes of the class by their name"*… (just saying…)

Comment: He doesn't have much choice :) (Although we'll see how the edit I'm currently working on turns out...)

Answer (score 0):

**This is just for fun, please do not ever ever ever do this**.

Python interns small numbers and only ever creates one copy. Internally, python trusts that these pointers aren't changed. It will create the small integers, and then store the pointers, telling itself "this pointer will **always** point to the correct number. *But, if you're sneaky enough, you can change what the pointer is pointing to, then when you tell python to give you an integer, say 1, it will look up the value at that memory location and spit it back to you, regardless of what it actually is.*

In comes [**`ctypes`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)!

```py
import ctypes
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 1
foo = Foo()
variables = [foo.a, foo.b, foo.c]
print(f"foo.a is {foo.a}. foo.b is {foo.b}. foo.c is {foo.c}.")
for v in variables:
    ctypes.cast(id(v), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))[6] = v-1
print("*~* ctypes magic *~*")
print(f"foo.a is {foo.a}. foo.b is {foo.b}. foo.c is {foo.c}.")
print(f".... But now 1 is {1}, 2 is {2}, and 3 is {3}... Oh no!")
```

Output:

```
foo.a is 3. foo.b is 2. foo.c is 1.
*~* ctypes magic *~*
foo.a is 2. foo.b is 1. foo.c is 0.
.... But now 1 is 0, 2 is 1, and 3 is 2... Oh no!
```

This *may* crash your interpretter. It may also make python segfault if you chose the right numbers~

Comment: Like, yeah, this is clever… but seriously… don't.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using a vector of symbolic references to the attributes

```
class VarVect:
    def __init__(self, foo, names):
        self.foo = foo
        self.names = names

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.names)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return getattr(self.foo, self.names[i])

    def __setitem__(self, i, val):
        setattr(self.foo, self.names[i], val)

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0.0
        self.b = 0.0
        self.c = 0.0
        self.var = VarVect(self, ('a', 'b', 'c'))

foo = Foo()

for i in range(len(foo.var)):
    foo.var[i] = 1.0

print(foo.a)
```

A drawback of such designs is that `foo.var[i] = 1.0` will be substantially slower than `foo.a = 1.0` if you have many assigments to make.